# how to make admin confirmatiom to show data in website

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I wrote this code to get confirmation of admin to show data in website, But I faced with this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I solve this problem?

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    CheckBox CheckBoxImg = (CheckBox)FindControl("CheckBoxImg");
    if (CheckBoxImg.Checked == true)
    {
        db.Open();
        SqlCommand MyCMD = new SqlCommand("select max(imid) from Gallery_image", db);
        int ID = 1;
        try
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(MyCMD.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {  //Do something with exception 
           Console.Writeline(ex.Message); }
        string Sflag = string.Empty;
        Sflag ="1";
        MyCMD.CommandText = "Insert into Gallery_image (flag) Values (@flag) WHERE imid="+ID;
        MyCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", Sflag);
        MyCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        db.Close();
    }
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ID="Image3" ImageUrl='<%#"~/gallery/" + Eval("imfilename").ToString().Trim()%>' runat="server" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxImg" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ok" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: On which line are you getting this error?

Comment: The only thing which could raise `NullReferenceException` in your code is `CheckBoxImg`

Comment: @Taleeb in this:"if (CheckBoxImg.Checked == true)"

Comment: @Shaharyar yes...so how can I solve that?

Comment: Please add the related aspx code here.

Comment: @niloofarsoft. FindControl("CheckBoxImg") is not returning the control. Are you sure "CheckBoxImg" is the id of the checkbox and that the checkbox is not within some other control?

Comment: @Shaharyar I added aspx code too... .

Comment: @Taleeb yes and I added my aspx code.can you find my problem?

Comment: @niloofarsoft ... Your `CheckBoxImg` is inside a `Repeater` control. This is why you can't access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your control is in repeater, you can not directly access it. You will have to loop through all of its items and get the `CheckBox`:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItem in Repeater1.Items)
{
    CheckBox CheckBoxImg = (CheckBox)repeaterItem.FindControl("CheckBoxImg");

    if (CheckBoxImg.Checked)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```